# Modify existing pdf (add/remove pages) while preserving metadata

Tags: c#, pdf, metadata, itext

my target is to open an existing pdf, add or remove some pages while preserving the metadata (Author, Subject, ...) in a Windows.Forms C# application.

I use iTextSharp and found examples how to add or remove pages by using the PdfConcatenate class. To keep the metadata I use a PdfStamper afterwards. To speed things up I want to do the modifications in memory before storing the result to disk.

The problem is NOT adding or removing the pages but to keep the metadata in the same step.
So can anybody tell me/giva an example on how to achieve this (better) or am I on the completely wrong track?

Here my current code (see comments for problem related lines):

```
public void RemovePagesInFile(string documentLocation, int pageIndexFrom, int pageCount)
{
    // TB: open the pdf
    using (PdfReader sourcePdfReader = new PdfReader(documentLocation))
    using (MemoryStream concatenatedTargetStream = new MemoryStream((int)sourcePdfReader.FileLength))
    {
        // TB: use a concatenator to create a new pdf containing only the desired pages
        PdfConcatenate concatenator = new PdfConcatenate(concatenatedTargetStream);

        // TB: create a list with the page numbers to keep
        List<int> pagesToKeep = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageIndexFrom; i++)
        {
            pagesToKeep.Add(i);
        }

        for (int i = pageIndexFrom + pageCount + 1; i <= sourcePdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            pagesToKeep.Add(i);
        }

        // TB: execute the page copy
        sourcePdfReader.SelectPages(pagesToKeep);
        concatenator.AddPages(sourcePdfReader);

        // TB: problem(s) here:
        // 1. when calling concatenator.Close() the memory stream gets disposed as expected.
        // concatenator.Close();
        // 2. even when calling concatenator.WriterFlush() the memory stream seems to be missing content (error when creating targetReader (see below)).
        // concatenator.Writer.Flush();
        // 3. when keeping concatenator open the same error as above occures (I assume not all bytes have been written to the memory stream)

        // TB: preserve the meta data from the source document
        // => ERROR here: "Rebuild trailer not found. Original Error: PDF startxref not found"
        using (PdfReader targetReader = new PdfReader(concatenatedTargetStream))
        using (MemoryStream targetStream = new MemoryStream((int)concatenatedTargetStream.Length))
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(targetReader, targetStream))
            {
                stamper.MoreInfo = sourcePdfReader.Info;

                // TB: same problem as above with stamper ?
                stamper.Close();
            }

            // TB: close the reader to be able to access the source pdf
            sourcePdfReader.Close();

            // TB: write the modified pdf to the disk
            File.WriteAllBytes(documentLocation, targetStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have more than 10 Reputation points, so can please anybody post the following as answer: ... EDIT: does not work either - the text is too long for comments *grrrr*

Comment: Plain and simple: The solution is to make two changes: 
call "concatenator.Writer.CloseStream = false" before calling "concatenator.Close()" and same for the PdfStamper. So if anybody with more reputations would add this as an answer: Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes need to be made.  Call

```
concatenator.Writer.CloseStream = false
```

before calling

```
concatenator.Close()
```

Do the same thing for the PdfStamper and you're set.